# Replacement for C-style loop in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

Swift 2.2 deprecated the C-style loop. However in some cases, the new range operator just doesn't work the same.

```
for var i = 0; i < -1; ++i { ... }
```

and

```
for i in 0..<-1 { ... }
```

The later one will fail at run-time. I can wrap the loop with an `if`, but it's a bit cluttered. Sometimes this kind of loop is useful.

Any thoughts?

**Use cases**

1. You need to enumerate all elements of an array, except the last one.
2. You need to enumerate all whole integer numbers in a decimal range, but the range can be like [0.5, 0.9] and so there's no integers (after some maths), which results in an empty loop.

Comment: Did your loop run ever run in Swift 2.2?

Comment: Yes it does, but is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Even if it was valid in Swift 2.2, the inner body never execute

Comment: No, not in the example. But sometimes I need to loop on a dynamically computed range, and the range may be empty.

Comment: You will have to use `for` loops only for iterating or sanitize your input, e.g. `for i in 0 ..< max(0, -1)`. Or use a `while`

Comment: Hey using `max` is actually a pretty good idea! Thanks. Still doesn't look as concise as the C-style one :(

Comment: Could you maybe add a real use case? We could probably find a much better solution.

Comment: @Sulthan Use case: you need to enumerate all the whole integers in a decimal range, but the range might be like [0.5, 0.9], and results in no whole integers (after some maths, of course), which results in an empty loop.

Comment: @Sulthan Or you need to enumerate all elements of an array, except the last one

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Then you should be using the functional style: `for item in array.dropLast()`. Will work even with empty arrays.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks very much! That will do it if an array is involved. Any thoughts on the decimal case? It's just so much convenient if there's a range operator that returns empty set if the lower end is greater than the higher end.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen I could pile on many other examples from my own code where loss of C-style for loop was sort of a disaster. They were all solvable but the result was far less elegant. I sometimes wonder how the inmates got to be in charge of the Swift madhouse...

Comment: Aside from the iteration problem, the run-time fail is because the implicit add is tested for overflow. Use the "overflow operators" `&+` and `&-` (and `&*`), which don't raise exceptions on overflow, if you intend to rely on wrap-around.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although it's not as "pretty", you can use `stride`:

```
for var i in 0.stride(to: -1, by: -1) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: I agree, drive-by downvote by someone who probably did not understand this solution. I believe the `by` should be `1` rather than `-1` though, to mirror the OP:s question: `0.stride(to: -1, by: 1) ...` will yield an empty stridethrough, equivalent to the "C-style loop" described by the OP, whereas   `0.stride(to: -1, by: -1) ...` will, _by coincident_ (strict `to<..from`), also yield an empty stridethough, whereas e.g. `0.stride(to: -2, by: -1) ...`, will not.

Answer (score 9):

### Mimicking the "C-style loop"

Not entirely pretty, but you can wrap the range:s upper bound with a `max(0, ..)` to ascertain it never takes negative values.

```
let foo : [Int] = []
for i in 0..<max(0,foo.count-1) {
    print(i)
}
```

I'd prefer, however, the [`from.stride(to:by)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html) solution (that has already been mentioned in the other answers, see e.g. Michael:s answer).

I think it's valuable to explicitly point out, however, that `from.stride(to:by)` neatly returns an empty `StrideTo` (or, if converted to an array: an empty array) if attempting to stride *to* a number that is less than *from* but *by* a positive stride. E.g., striding from `0` to `-42` by `1` will not attempt to stride all the way through `"∞ -> -∞ -> -42"` (i.e., an error case), but simply returns an empty `StrideTo` (as it should):

```
Array(0.stride(to: -42, by: 1)) // []

// -> equivalent to your C loop:
for i in 0.stride(to: foo.count-1, by: 1) { 
    print(i) 
}
```

### Use case 1: enumerate all but the last element of an array

For this specific use case, a simple solution is using `dropLast()` (as described by Sulthan in the comments to your question) followed by `forEach`.

```
let foo = Array(1...5)
foo.dropLast().forEach { print($0) } // 1 2 3 4
```

Or, if you need more control over what to drop out, apply a filter to your array

```
let foo = Array(1...5)
foo.filter { $0 < foo.count }.forEach { print($0) } // 1 2 3 4
```

### Use case 2: enumerate all integers in a decimal range, allowing this enumeration to be empty

For your decimal/double *closed interval* example (`[0.6, 0.9]`; an interval rather than a range in the context of Swift syntax), you can convert the closed interval to an integer range (using `ceil` function) and apply a `forEach` over the latter

```
let foo : (ClosedInterval<Double>) -> () = {
    (Int(ceil($0.start))..<Int(ceil($0.end)))
        .forEach { print($0) }
}

foo(0.5...1.9) // 1
foo(0.5...0.9) // nothing
```

Or, if you specifically want to enumerate the (possible) integers contained in this interval; use as en extension fit to your purpose:

```
protocol MyDoubleBounds {
    func ceilToInt() -> Int
}

extension Double: MyDoubleBounds {
    func ceilToInt() -> Int {
        return Int(ceil(self)) // no integer bounds check in this simple example
    }
}

extension ClosedInterval where Bound: MyDoubleBounds {
    func enumerateIntegers() -> EnumerateSequence<(Range<Int>)> {
        return (self.start.ceilToInt()
            ..< self.end.ceilToInt())
            .enumerate()
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
for (i, intVal) in (1.3...3.2).enumerateIntegers() {
    print(i, intVal)
} /* 0 2
     1 3 */

for (i, intVal) in (0.6...0.9).enumerateIntegers() {
    print(i, intVal)
} /* nothing */
```

Answer (score 4):

*For reference:*
In swift 3.0 stride is now defined globally which makes for loop look more natural:

```
for i in stride(from: 10, to: 0, by: -1){
    print(i)
} /* 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 */
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3 and need to change the "index"**

```
for var index in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 1){}
```