# Trying to convert C-Style statement to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I understand this question has been asked before and I have tried to understand the answers to apply to the code I am working with, for example both; [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173379/warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-ve) & [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166907/replacement-for-c-style-loop-in-swift-2-2)

Previous Code with Error

```
let n = mutableRows.count
var i = 0, rows: [IndexPath] = []

for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  rows.append(mutableRows[i] as! IndexPath)
}
```

My Update to Swift 3.0

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: n, by: +1){
  rows.append(mutableRows[i] as! IndexPath)
}
```

Even thought I don't get any errors the function does not work. Does anyone know how to correctly change the For statement to Swift 3.0 ?

Here's the full code;

```
func longPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = gesture.location(in: self)
    let indexPath = indexPathForRow(at: location)
    let sections = numberOfSections
    var rows = 0
    for i in 0 ..< sections {
        rows += numberOfRows(inSection: i)
    }

    // get out of here if the long press was not on a valid row or our table is empty
    // or the dataSource tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath: doesn't allow moving the row
    if (rows == 0 || (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began && indexPath == nil) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended && currentLocationIndexPath == nil)) {
            cancelGesture()
            return
    }

    // started
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        isEnabled = false
        let cell = cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!;
        //            draggingRowHeight = cell.frame.size.height;
        cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
        cell.setHighlighted(false, animated: false)

        // make an image from the pressed tableview cell
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.bounds.size, false, 0)
        cell.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let cellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // create and image view that we will drag around the screen
        if draggingView == nil {
            draggingView = UIImageView(image: cellImage)
            addSubview(draggingView!)
            let rect = rectForRow(at: indexPath!)
            draggingView!.frame = draggingView!.bounds.offsetBy(dx: rect.origin.x, dy: rect.origin.y)

            // add drop shadow to image and lower opacity
            draggingView!.layer.masksToBounds = false
            draggingView!.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            draggingView!.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0);
            draggingView!.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
            draggingView!.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
            draggingView!.layer.opacity = Float(draggingViewOpacity);

            // zoom image towards user
            UIView.beginAnimations("zoom", context: nil)
            draggingView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1);
            draggingView!.center = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: location.y);
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
        cell.isHidden = true;
        currentLocationIndexPath = indexPath;
        initialIndexPath = indexPath;

        // enable scrolling for cell
        scrollDisplayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(SBGestureTableView.scrollTableWithCell(_:)))
        scrollDisplayLink?.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    }
        // dragging
    else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        var rect = bounds;
        // adjust rect for content inset as we will use it below for calculating scroll zones
        rect.size.height -= contentInset.top;
        let location = gesture.location(in: self);
        // tell us if we should scroll and which direction
        let scrollZoneHeight = rect.size.height / 6;
        let bottomScrollBeginning = contentOffset.y + contentInset.top + rect.size.height - scrollZoneHeight;
        let topScrollBeginning = contentOffset.y + contentInset.top  + scrollZoneHeight;
        // we're in the bottom zone
        if location.y >= bottomScrollBeginning {
            scrollRate = Double((location.y - bottomScrollBeginning) / scrollZoneHeight);
        }
            // we're in the top zone
        else if (location.y <= topScrollBeginning) {
            scrollRate = Double((location.y - topScrollBeginning) / scrollZoneHeight);
        }
        else {
            scrollRate = 0;
        }
    }
        // dropped
    else if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        isEnabled = true
        let indexPath: IndexPath = currentLocationIndexPath!
        let cell = cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        // remove scrolling CADisplayLink
        scrollDisplayLink?.invalidate();
        scrollDisplayLink = nil;
        scrollRate = 0;

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            let rect = self.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
            self.draggingView!.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.draggingView!.frame = self.draggingView!.bounds.offsetBy(dx: rect.origin.x, dy: rect.origin.y)
            }, completion: {(Bool) -> Void in
                self.draggingView!.removeFromSuperview()
                cell.isHidden = false
                let visibleRows: NSArray = self.indexPathsForVisibleRows! as NSArray
                let mutableRows = visibleRows.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                mutableRows.remove(indexPath)

                let n = mutableRows.count
                var i = 0, rows: [IndexPath] = []


                for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
                   rows.append(mutableRows[i] as! IndexPath)
                }


                self.reloadRows(at: rows as [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
                self.currentLocationIndexPath = nil
                self.draggingView = nil
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `for row in mutableRows { rows.append(row) ...` (available since Swift 1.0)

Comment: PS: and why this ObjectiveC-ish `mutableCopy` and `NSMutableArray`?? Learn to use the benefit of Swift's native types, the difference of `let` and `var` and its strong type system. For example with `indexPathsForVisibleRows! as NSArray` you throw away the type information and have to re-cast it. That's pretty inefficient.

Comment: @vadian because row is actually type `int` and has no member `append`

Comment: No, at the mentioned moment `rows` is `[IndexPath]` -> see the line `var i = 0, rows: [IndexPath] = []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
for row in mutableRows {
    rows.append(row as! IndexPath)
}
```

The for...in loop is very useful. In every iteration, the value of `row` is changed to the next item in the `mutableRowsArray`. And the loop ends when all items in the array has been iterated.

This is even simpler!

```
rows = mutableRows.map { $0 as! IndexPath }
```

Comment: I'm getting the error Value of type 'Int' has no member 'append' for `rows.append` this is because it isn't an array. `var rows = 0
        for i in 0 ..< sections {
            rows += numberOfRows(inSection: i)
        }`

Comment: You're using `rows` twice (as `Int` and `[IndexPath]`). That's ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: Apparently you have two `rows` variables. It's very confusing if you can't tell already. Change the name of one of them. @JKSDEV

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah sorry, just re-read the code and fixed the naming and it works now. Thanks !! Sorry my boss is stressing me out about converting this to Swift 3 by tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

You can directly append the array:

```
let visibleRows = (self.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [])
    .filter { $0 != indexPath }

rows.append(contentsOf: visibleRows)
```

There is no need to use `NSMutableArray` in Swift.